# How can my app be notified when a window belonging to another app is moved?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My app gives online poker rooms a "head-up display". It superimposes info on top of the poker table window.

Currently my app uses the Accessibility API to detect the location and size of the poker table's window. It polls once per second. Is there a way to do this with notifications rather than with polling?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know myself, but have a look at https://github.com/kballard/NotificationWatcher for a tool that shows all the workspace and distributed notifications. If there's a notification to listen to, you can find it using that tool.